# Linux.BtcMine.717 in canonical-livepatchd

Tags: malware, antivirus, canonical-livepatch

today Dr.Web for Linux (antivirus) is detecting virus in

Menace : Linux.BtcMine.717
Détecté par le module : Scanner
Heure de détection : 17/6/23 2:42 Μ.Μ.
Nom de l’objet : canonical-livepatchd
Titulaire : root
Modifié : 17/6/23 2:42 Μ.Μ.
Taille : 9.44 Mo

Chemin :
/snap/canonical-livepatch/229/canonical-livepatchd

Should I consider this as serious?or false positive? Does not make sense canonical would send infected updates.
Has anyone insights about this?I am considering to reinstall a fresh copy of Ubuntu but not sure it will change anything if LivePatch resend this update
Thanks anyone for your help. At this moment, I believe this is a false positive but have never had any virus result with this tool so I am surprised